# Why would my app not be able to "attach" an action?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, keyboard-events

I've changed my app class type from `NSObject` to `NSApplication` and now I get the following message when testing my app:

> Could not connect the action buttonClicked: to target of class NSApplication

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSApplication` does not respond to the `buttonClicked:` method and, therefore, there is no way for the target/action connection to be successfully made.

Comment: Moshe: Connect the button to an object that *does* respond to `buttonClicked:`. Perhaps you meant to connect it to your application delegate?

Comment: @Peter - This is the first time I am working on a desktop Cocoa app. I'm coming from iOS development and I'm making a Mac version of my app, baset on Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer class. How do I *attach* an action? (please post some sample or a link please.)

Comment: Moshe: Ctrl-drag from the object sending the action to the desired target. Interface Builder will show a pop-up with the available actions to connect it to; if you named your button and the correct action similarly (i.e., your action actually describes what it's supposed to do, not the view that will trigger it), Interface Builder will even position the correct action right under your mouse cursor for you, so all you'll have to do is click.

Comment: Moshe: Also, I'm curious what provoked the question in your last comment, because you clearly hooked up the button before (to the application object). You hook it up to any other object the same way: ctrl-drag to it and pick the action.

Comment: If you have a firm grasp of connections, but receive an error as per Moshe, check your IBAction method signature.

While this works in iOS:
`- (IBAction)apply;`

It failed as above on an OS X app (or perhaps because of Xcode 4).

So resolution was to use:
`- (IBAction)apply:(id)sender;`