# app crashes when button clicked

Tags: macos

I am from iOS dev background. I am creating simple mac app in the appdelegate I am adding NSViewController instance to the window and I have a button in the NSViewController class. When I click the button it crashes. I looked at these posts but I could not figure out whats wrong in my app.
[Why would my app not be able to "attach" an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886029/why-would-my-app-not-be-able-to-attach-an-action)

Here is the code in app delegate

```
PrViewController *pcVC = [[PrViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PrViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:pcVC.view];
```

Function for button

```
    -(IBAction)startClicked:(id)sender{NSLog@"Btn selected";}
```

When I click on the button, app crashes.
Following is the stack trace:

```
Producer_consumer[45914:303] -[__NSCFType startClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101d07680
 Producer_consumer[45914:303] -[__NSCFType startClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101d07680
Producer_consumer[45914:303] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff900deb06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ce803f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9017540a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff900cd02e ___forwarding___ + 414
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff900cce18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff85862959 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 342
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff858627b7 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 85
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff858626eb -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 138
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff85860bd3 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1855
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff85860421 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 504
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8585fb9c -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 820
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8585750e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff85853644 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8576921a -[NSApplication run] + 636
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8570dbd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
15  Producer_consumer                   0x0000000100001c02 main + 34
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff920127e1 start + 0
```

)

Any help would be appreciate
Thanks

Comment: What is the error? What line does it crash on.

Comment: What's the stack trace too?

Comment: It crashes when I click the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the view controller is being released prematurely because you are not holding a reference to it:

```
PrViewController *pcVC = [[PrViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PrViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:pcVC.view];
```

You need to make `pcVC` an instance variable of the class using the view or better still shake your iOS background and stop using view controllers altogether in favour of loading the view straight from NIB.

This [article](http://imlocation.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/strange-objects-nscftype-indicate-memory-management-bugs/) gave me the idea about it being memory management related.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Not sure how I missed this basic.

Answer (score 0):

Open your controller in Interface Builder and look at its actions (right click on orange circle). Looks like you have a broken action link. This can be the result of action renaming, or deleting and then adding method again.

Comment: I check it but the action seems to be intact.