# NSButton IBAction Crash unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch

Running into a simple problem and not quite sure what is causing it. Linked a NSButton up to a ViewController xib. The property is referenced and then I linked up the IBAction to the view controllers view. I'm getting a crash whenever I press the button with an unrecognized selector message. I know I'm doing something wrong but on iOS this is pretty standard.

Here is the code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    IPVLocationViewController *mainViewController = [[IPVLocationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"IPVLocationViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.contentView = mainViewController.view;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *mainButton;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}

- (IBAction)mainClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"THE BUTTON WAS CLICKED");
}


@end
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Nib , it looks like your view controller instance is of type NSViewController instead of MainViewController.

So select the view controller in your Nib (or storyboard), and change its type to MainViewController.

Of course, if this view controller isn't being loaded from a nib or storyboard, then just check where you create it and make sure you created an instance of the correct class.

Comment: In by Nib, files owner is marked as MainViewController. I'll add an image of what my Nib looks like. Image shows the relationships too. The subclass is marked as NSViewController for MainViewController.

Comment: Are your connections hooked up properly. If so , I would insist you to check the outlet connections again, and hunt for the unconnected buttons.

Comment: I added a screen shot showing the [self class] log which is of type MainViewController. Everything is connected as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

The accepted answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821134/app-crashes-when-button-clicked) helped me:

Needed to hold a reference to the view controller in the AppDelegate.

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MainViewController *mainViewController;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.contentView = self.mainViewController.view;

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```